# Add data to google spreadsheet with javascript or php

Tags: php, google-sheets, save

I tries searching on many places to know how to data to google spreadsheet with javascript but found nothing that can help me. I found a zend php library that we can use to add data to google spreadsheet but it requires user google user name and password which I don't have. I want rest api to access google spreadsheet and add data to users spreadsheet by getting authorizations from them. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I coded a simple java script library which can get data from the google spread sheets once they are published. [Gsheet2json](http://rumal.github.com/Gsheet2json/)

I am using the google custom forms to fill in the spreadsheet and above to retrieve.

Comment: Hi rumalp Thanks for replying. The form in my case will be dynamic and I don't know in hand how many fields the form will have. I have used oauth 2.0 using php to get permissions from user to read, write spreadsheet on their behalf and I am able to read google spreadsheet without publishing them publicly but now I am stuck on how to write data to spreadsheet. I just need to know the format the google spreadsheet need to save data to it. The zend pho library needs user name,password of user to save data to spreadsheet so I cannot use it. I need to save data to spreadsheet using oauth 2.0.